# Java Socket Client Stuck While Trying to Connect

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a server that's written in Python on Raspbian and a client that's written in Java for Android. Reversed (with the Raspberry Pi being the client and the phone being the server) it works fine using the same ports.
Here is the server:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.bind(('', 6969))
    print("Binded")
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
sock.listen(5)
print("Listening")
client, address = sock.accept() #gets stuck here
print("Connected")
sock.close()
print("Closed, bye bye")
```

Here is the client:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.i("RCJeff", "trying");
                Socket socket1 = new Socket("192.168.220.1", 6969); //gets stuck here
                Log.i("RCJeff", "connected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("RCJeff", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Added Internet permission of course. This is right after setContentView.
Server gets stuck at listening and client gets stuck at trying.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong? It works fine when I connect like this from my computer:

```
try {
        System.out.println("trying");
        Socket connectionSocket = new Socket("192.168.220.1", 6969);
        connectionSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks